# How can i save the user rating of each product in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

how can I save user rates for each product in WooCommerce? is there a build in function in WooCommerce or I should do it on my own in my plugin
I don't want to use plugins

Comment: Do you want to add review/rating programmatically ? because WooCommerce already do this by it self

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce saves rating by its own, but still, if you want to add some extra information at the time of rating of products then you may use this **comment_post** hook.